# Random Dice Project using PIC18

Tags: c, emulation, microcontroller

I'm working on a random number generator using a PIC18 CPU.

The digits are not displaying if the button is pushed and my emulator shows the error message in Proteus:

`[PIC18] PC=0x0000. $MCLR$ is low. Processor is in reset. [U1]`

Here is my code:

```
#pragma config MCLRE=OFF

sbit   DIS1   at PORTD.B6;     //Define Display 1 at Port D pin RD 6
sbit   DIS2   at PORTD.B7;     //Define Display 2 at Port D pin RD


unsigned char Code[10]={0x40, 0x79, 0x24, 0x30, 0x19, 0x12, 0x02, 0x78, 0x00, 0x10};
unsigned char DEC, DIG, DEL; //Define variable
void MSDelay (unsigned char Time) //Delay
{
   unsigned char y,z; //Define variable
   for (y=0; y<Time; y++) //For loop for Delay
   for (z=0; z<254; z++); //For loop for Delay
}

void main () //Main Function
{
  TRISC = 0;//Define PORTC as Output Port
  TRISD.RD6 = 0; //Define RD6 as Output Pin
  TRISD.RD7 = 0; //Define RD7 as Output Pin
  DIS1= 0;//Turn OFF Display 1
  DIS2= 0; //Turn OFF Display
  while (1) //End-Less Loop
{
for (DEC=0; DEC<10;DEC++)
{
    for (DIG=0; DIG<10; DIG++) //For Loop for Display Digit Number
    {
        for (DEL=0; DEL<10; DEL++) //Delay for next digit
        {
                DIS1 = 1; //Turn ON Display 1
                PORTC = Code [DEC]; //Find code and send to the PORTC
                MSDelay(10) ; //Delay for Turning ON the display
                DIS1 = 0; //Turn OFF Display I
                DIS2 = 1; //Turn ON Display
                PORTC= Code [DIG]; //Find code and send to the PORTC
                MSDelay (10) ; //Delay for Turning ON the display
                DIS2 = 0;//Turn OFF Display 2
                }
    }
}
}
}
```

[The schematics of my setup can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrdh3.png)

What is the problem?

Comment: Fyi, if you think you asked a question, read what you posted and point it out, because I read it twice and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

> [PIC18] PC=0x0000. $MCLR$ is low. Processor is in reset. [U1]
>
> ```
> #pragma config MCLRE=OFF
> ```

Not all simulators support the microcontroller configuration (`#pragma config`).

I even found [a forum entry](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m663143.aspx) on the Microchip website that this may not work with real microcontrollers!

"$MCLR$ is low. Processor is in reset." means that your simulator does not care about the `#pragma config MCLRE=OFF` line.

You have a lot of unused pins. I would use a different pin (e.g. RE0 instead of RE3).

Personally, I would also not change the controller configuration of a real microcontroller (`#pragma config`) unless it is really necessary:

If something goes wrong, you may brick the microcontroller and it cannot be used any longer.